Are multiple EMF sources considered series-opposing in a parallel circuit?
In the parallel circuit attached, is it correct to call the loop A-B-I-J series-opposing? Or is B-I just another leg of a parallel circuit? Asked another way, does an opposing EMF source such as BAT1 become series-opposing to Alt1 when there are multiple current paths?

Why do you want to call it anything when you have a circuit image that fully describes it?

Yes, it's obviously a parallel circuit. The discussion/argument has come up in an automotive forum that a-b-i-j is "series-opposing' and somehow electrically separate from the other legs.

Unless the battery is nonideal you have connected two different voltages in parallel. This is nonsense.
I am not acquainted with the nomenclature "series-opposing." In any case, it doesn't matter what you call it. The circuit diagram (and the models for elements, if nonideal) define the circuit well enough for me.

The battery in this diagram will charge at 14V alternator voltage. Series-opposing refers to a series circuit with opposing EMF sources. Not as useful as a series-aiding circuit, where the EMF voltages add.

If you break the connection I-J, or A-B, and insert a component there (say a resistor), then the voltage across the added component would be 14 - 13.5 = 0.5V.  The parallel branches are then irrelevant, and yes, "series opposing" would be an adequate description of the highlighted section.
As shown, they are shorted together, which is a contradiction if both elements are ideal voltage sources (as we often model them to be).  If we use Thevenin equivalent sources, the equivalent voltage and resistance must be defined, and then the circuit is solvable.
Note the meaningfulness of "series opposing" will be lost when the circuit is expanded with non-zero-resistance Thevenin equivalents.  In that case, it would be more that they are all just legs, or branches, between the main node(s).
A ground should also be shown, to make it easier to reference node voltages against an assumed reference, or to enter this into a circuit simulator.
Given your comment, it sounds like this may be a circuit where Thevenin equivalents must be defined.

Thanks Tim. My poor diagram is meant to represent a typical automobile, where the alternator powers all loads and charges the battery. F-J is a common ground. Current is divided among the loads along A-E. BAT1 will be at 14V with Alt1 charging, 13.5V when Alt1 is not charging. So is this a simple parallel circuit or partially series?

I would call that a parallel system, yes.
